# PDF itext form.setField How does text display center vertically?

Tags: itext

I made a PDF template with adobeDC, I added form fields to the template, now I want the text in the form to be centered vertically, but the setFieldProperty() method cannot center text vertically, now I want com.itextpdf.text.But this paragraph may need absolute positioning, but I am not sure how much text content, I want to know if there is an easy way, please help me

The exported PDF is mainly used for printing

jar version:itextpdf-5.5.0.jar

```
form.setField(name, top+map.get(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int pageNo = form.getFieldPositions(name).get(0).page;
Rectangle signRect = form.getFieldPositions(name).get(0).position;
float x = signRect.getLeft();
float y = signRect.getBottom();
PdfContentByte under = ps.getOverContent(pageNo);
ColumnText column = new ColumnText(under);
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell pdfCell = new PdfPCell();
pdfCell.setMinimumHeight(40);
pdfCell.disableBorderSide(15);
pdfCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
Font font2 = new Font(bfChinese, 7,Font.NORMAL);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(map.get(name),font2);
pdfCell.setPhrase(paragraph);
table.addCell(pdfCell);
column.addElement(table);column.setSimpleColumn(signRect.getLeft()-25,signRect.getBottom(),signRect.getRight()+25,signRect.getTop());
column.go();
```

Comment: Please be aware that your code does **not anymore fill in the form field**, instead it **paints something in the static content underneath the form field** or more exactly under the first widget of the form field. If your PDF fill-ins afterwards are to be read programmatically, they won't be found.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the warning.Since the PDF I exported is printed, the above code meets my requirements.